# Align content of all cards in the modal box

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need help in getting CSS of different cards inside the modal box fixed. I want all cards to use the same column width for different content inside it. So that all cards look symmetric. Check the picture below, they all look zigzag. Check the alignment of Buy buttons in different cards.

[image]

```
<!--Card-->
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <input type="text" id="market-search" onkeyup="marketSearch()" placeholder="Search for stock names..">
         <i class="fa fa-times" data-dismiss="modal"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="card stock-card" data-name="{{ stock.name }}">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">ABB India Ltd.</h4>
                  <div class="market-info">
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:{{ stock.code }}">Details</a></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info up" id="diff"> 9.45
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     </p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><strong>$</strong> <span id="price">1340</span></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info">ABB</p>
                     <input id="input_{{stock.code}}"/>
                     <a style="white-space:nowrap" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-success " onclick=insertRow("{{stock.code}}","{{stock.name|to_and}}","{{stock.price}}","{{stock.diff}}")>Buy</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card stock-card" data-name="{{ stock.name }}">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">ACC Ltd.</h4>
                  <div class="market-info">
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:{{ stock.code }}">Details</a></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info up" id="diff"> 19.45
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     </p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><strong>$</strong> <span id="price">134</span></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info">ACCBank</p>
                     <input id="input_{{stock.code}}"/>
                     <a style="white-space:nowrap" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-success " onclick=insertRow("{{stock.code}}","{{stock.name|to_and}}","{{stock.price}}","{{stock.diff}}")>Buy</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card stock-card" data-name="{{ stock.name }}">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">INFY </h4>
                  <div class="market-info">
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:{{ stock.code }}">Details</a></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info down" id="diff"> 0.45
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     </p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><strong>$</strong> <span id="price">805</span></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info">INFOSYS</p>
                     <input id="input_{{stock.code}}"/>
                     <a style="white-space:nowrap" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-success " onclick=insertRow("{{stock.code}}","{{stock.name|to_and}}","{{stock.price}}","{{stock.diff}}")>Buy</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card stock-card" data-name="{{ stock.name }}">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">ABBACUS India Ltd.</h4>
                  <div class="market-info">
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:{{ stock.code }}">Details</a></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info up" id="diff"> 9.45
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     </p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><strong>$</strong> <span id="price">13</span></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info">ABBACUS</p>
                     <input id="input_{{stock.code}}"/>
                     <a style="white-space:nowrap" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-success " onclick=insertRow("{{stock.code}}","{{stock.name|to_and}}","{{stock.price}}","{{stock.diff}}")>Buy</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card stock-card" data-name="{{ stock.name }}">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Reliance</h4>
                  <div class="market-info">
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:{{ stock.code }}">Details</a></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info up" id="diff"> 9.45
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     </p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info"><strong>$</strong> <span id="price">1200</span></p>
                     <p class="card-text stock-info">RELIANCE</p>
                     <input id="input_{{stock.code}}"/>
                     <a style="white-space:nowrap" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-success " onclick=insertRow("{{stock.code}}","{{stock.name|to_and}}","{{stock.price}}","{{stock.diff}}")>Buy</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card {
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.card .card-title {
    font-weight: 300;
}

.card .market-info .card-text {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.card .market-info .stock-info
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-align: right;
}

.card .market-info .up {
    color: green;
}

.card .market-info .down {
    color: red;
}

.card .market-info input{
  max-width:60px;
  margin-right:5px;
  padding:4px;
}

.card .market-info .stock-info
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;/*Change HERE*/
    text-align: right;
}

.card .market-info{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap; 
  align-items:center;
}

.card .market-info p{
  margin:0;
}

.modal-lg {
    max-width: 40% !important;
}
```

I am not able to fix it. Any help here is highly appreciated?

Link to codepen https://codepen.io/agrawalo/pen/NWKaWMm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this css

```
.card .market-info{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap; 
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between; /*Add this property*/
}
```